# What does the abbreviation "ext" mean in Python libraries?

Tags: python

In a lot of Python libraries I see a module called "ext", for example `sqlalchemy.ext`. I was just curious what the abbreviation means and what the module is usually used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is used to namespace external packages that are not part of the core but provide added functionality.

I like the rational that `Flask` uses. They use `ext` as a [generic namespace proxy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensiondev/#extension-import-transition) to load external modules.

On `import flask.ext.foo`, it first tries to find `flask_foo`, then `flaskext.foo`

This makes it easier for end users to remember a naming pattern and lets the library figure out where to load the extension from.

Answer (score 1):

Extended or extension, i.e. features / functionalities beyond the core.

Comment: That's quite broad and vague... Wouldn't you say that *most* of the code in a project is beyond the core?

Comment: This is at least true for [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/index.html) i.e. the doc introduces the 'ext' package as "SQLAlchemy has a variety of ORM extensions available, which add additional functionality to the core behavior."

Comment: Same for [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensiondev/#ext-import-transition)